# Open/Save/Save As default settings

Tags: windows

Does anyone know how to set/change the default settings for the "Open/Save/Save As" dialog?  I don't mean code wise, I mean for Windows itself?  Mine is **ALWAYS** coming up in as a list in *reverse alphabetical* order and it's annoying as all heck!

Comment: What Windows OS version are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows XP and older you can use [OpenWide](http://speak.geek.nz/code/openwide) which allows to change some of the settings for the open/save dialog.

Another solution could be [FlashFolder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flashfolder/) which has an [option to remember the last view mode](http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=162926).